# Modify existing json schema

Tags: jsonschema

If I have 2 schemas: A and B. The only difference between them is that B has `minProperties` attribute on it. Is there any way to instead of duplicating everything inside and adding that `minProperties` I could use json refs (`$ref` attribute)?

To visualise:

- schema A:

```
{
  "id": "A",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    ... lots of props ...
  }
}
```

- schema B

```
{
  "id": "B",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "minProperties": 1,
  "properties": {
    ... lots of props, excatly the same as schema A ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `definitions/$defs` to factor out the base schema, then reference it in multiple places using additional constraints

Using draft-2020-12, you can use sibling properties with a `$ref`

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "thing_with": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/thing",
            "minProperties": 1
        },
        "thing_without": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/thing"
        }
    },
    "$defs": {
        "thing": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "property": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Using draft-04 - 2019-09,  you need to use an `allOf` to compose the schema

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "thing_with": {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/thing"
                },
                {
                    "minProperties": 2
                }
            ]
        },
        "thing_without": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/thing"
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "thing": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "property": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```